Ffmpeg out of memory issues with filter_complex_script
I’m trying to do a "moving crop" on a video with ffmpeg, following this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78314831/ffmpeg-dynamic-cropping-using-sendcmd-correct-syntax
I’m specifying the crop coordinates in a file
!ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i input.mp4 -filter_complex_script crop_coordinates.txt -map "[out]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -r 29.97 output.mp4

My file looks like:
nullsrc=608x1080:r=29.97[cv];
[cv][0]overlay=-642:-0:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,0)'[b0];
[b0][0]overlay=-642:-0:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,1)'[b1];
[b1][0]overlay=-642:-0:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,2)'[b2];
...

My problem is that when I try to run the ffmpeg command, I’m encountering out of memory issues (google colab stops my command with ^C). I use the whole google colab RAM which is 12GB. Edit: just tried with a 30GB RAM machine and also exhausted the memory.
The problem seems to be related to the size of the txt file, not the size of the input video. If my file contains few lines (up to 900 according to my tests), the command runs successfully. More than that and I get memory issues. Even if my input video is a 5s clip of resolution 1920x1080, I get OOM issues with more than 900 lines. It seems a bit weird because a file with 900 lines corresponds to a 56KB file and a final 30s video... which is not that much!
So is there a way to avoid that? Like limit ffmpeg overall memory consumption, or load multiple small files instead of a big one? Speed is not that big of a deal for me, I just want my command not to be interrupted no matter the size of the txt file.
